# Magic Square (Python)

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, matrix, mathematics

#### Problem

Write a method to return a boolean if an input grid is magic square.

---

A magic square is a \$NxN\$ square grid (where N is the number of cells on each side) filled with distinct positive integers in the range \${1,2,...,n^{2}}\$ such that each cell contains a different integer and the sum of the integers in each row, column and diagonal is equal. The sum is called the magic constant or magic sum of the magic square.

[image]

---

#### Code

I've tried to solve the above problem. If you'd like to review the code and provide any change/improvement recommendations please do so, and I'd really appreciate that.

```
from typing import List
import numpy as np


def is_magic_square(grid: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
    """Returns a boolean if an input grid is magic square"""
    try:
        grid_length = len(grid)
        magic_sum = float(grid_length * (grid_length ** 2 + 1) / 2)
        diag_positive, diag_negative = [], []
        diag_count_positive = 0
        diag_count_negative = grid_length - 1
        col_grid = np.zeros(shape=(grid_length, grid_length))
        unique_elements = set()
        for index_row, lists in enumerate(grid):
            diag_negative.append(lists[diag_count_negative])
            diag_count_negative -= 1

            if len(grid[index_row]) != grid_length:
                return False

            if sum(lists) != magic_sum:
                return False

            for index_col in range(grid_length):
                unique_elements.add(lists[index_col])
                col_grid[index_col][index_row] = lists[index_col]
                if index_col == grid_length and index_row == grid_length - 1 and len(unique_elements) != grid_length ** 2 - 1:
                    return False

            if index_row == grid_length - 1:
                sum_col = sum(col_grid)
                temp_col = np.array([magic_sum] * grid_length)
                if str(temp_col) != str(sum_col):
                    return False

            if diag_count_positive == index_row:
                diag_positive.append(lists[index_row])
                diag_count_positive += 1

                if diag_count_positive == grid_length and sum(diag_positive) != magic_sum:
                    return False

            if index_row == grid_length - 1 and sum(diag_negative) != magic_sum:
                return False
    except:
        return False

    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ---------------------------- TEST ---------------------------
    DIVIDER_DASH_LINE = '-' * 50
    GREEN_APPLE = '\U0001F34F'
    RED_APPLE = '\U0001F34E'

    magic_squares = [
        [[4, 3, 8],
         [9, 5, 1],
         [2, 7, 6]],


        [[9, 3, 22, 16, 15],
         [2, 21, 20, 14, 8],
         [25, 19, 13, 7, 1],
         [18, 12, 6, 5, 24],
         [11, 10, 4, 23, 17]],

        [[60, 53, 44, 37, 4, 13, 20, 29],
         [3, 14, 19, 30, 59, 54, 43, 38],
         [58, 55, 42, 39, 2, 15, 18, 31],
         [1, 16, 17, 32, 57, 56, 41, 40],
         [61, 52, 45, 36, 5, 12, 21, 28],
         [6, 11, 22, 27, 62, 51, 46, 35],
         [63, 50, 47, 34, 7, 10, 23, 26],
         [8, 9, 24, 25, 64, 49, 48, 33]],


        [[35, 26, 17, 1, 62, 53, 44],
         [46, 37, 21, 12, 3, 64, 55],
         [57, 41, 32, 23, 14, 5, 66],
         [61, 52, 43, 34, 25, 16, 7],
         [2, 63, 54, 45, 36, 27, 11],
         [13, 4, 65, 56, 47, 31, 22],
         [24, 15, 6, 67, 51, 42, 33]],

        [[1, 35, 4, 33, 32, 6],
         [25, 11, 9, 28, 8, 30],
         [24, 14, 18, 16, 17, 22],
         [13, 23, 19, 21, 20, 15],
         [12, 26, 27, 10, 29, 7],
         [36, 2, 34, 3, 5, 31]],


        [[16, 14, 7, 30, 23],
         [24, 17, 10, 8, 31],
         [32, 25, 18, 11, 4],
         [5, 28, 26, 19, 12],
         [13, 6, 29, 22, 20]],


        [[1, 14, 4, 15],
         [8, 11, 5, 10],
         [13, 2, 16, 3],
         [12, 7, 9, 6]],


        [[8, 1, 6],
         [3, 5, 7],
         [4, 9, 2]]
    ]

    for magic_square in magic_squares:
        print(DIVIDER_DASH_LINE)
        if is_magic_square(magic_square) is True:
            print(f'{GREEN_APPLE} "{magic_square}" is a magic square.')
        else:
            print(f'{RED_APPLE} "{magic_square}" is not a magic square.')
```

#### Output

```
--------------------------------------------------
 "[[4, 3, 8], [9, 5, 1], [2, 7, 6]]" is a magic square.
--------------------------------------------------
 "[[9, 3, 22, 16, 15], [2, 21, 20, 14, 8], [25, 19, 13, 7, 1], [18, 12, 6, 5, 24], [11, 10, 4, 23, 17]]" is a magic square.
--------------------------------------------------
 "[[60, 53, 44, 37, 4, 13, 20, 29], [3, 14, 19, 30, 59, 54, 43, 38], [58, 55, 42, 39, 2, 15, 18, 31], [1, 16, 17, 32, 57, 56, 41, 40], [61, 52, 45, 36, 5, 12, 21, 28], [6, 11, 22, 27, 62, 51, 46, 35], [63, 50, 47, 34, 7, 10, 23, 26], [8, 9, 24, 25, 64, 49, 48, 33]]" is a magic square.
--------------------------------------------------
 "[[35, 26, 17, 1, 62, 53, 44], [46, 37, 21, 12, 3, 64, 55], [57, 41, 32, 23, 14, 5, 66], [61, 52, 43, 34, 25, 16, 7], [2, 63, 54, 45, 36, 27, 11], [13, 4, 65, 56, 47, 31, 22], [24, 15, 6, 67, 51, 42, 33]]" is not a magic square.
--------------------------------------------------
 "[[1, 35, 4, 33, 32, 6], [25, 11, 9, 28, 8, 30], [24, 14, 18, 16, 17, 22], [13, 23, 19, 21, 20, 15], [12, 26, 27, 10, 29, 7], [36, 2, 34, 3, 5, 31]]" is a magic square.
--------------------------------------------------
 "[[16, 14, 7, 30, 23], [24, 17, 10, 8, 31], [32, 25, 18, 11, 4], [5, 28, 26, 19, 12], [13, 6, 29, 22, 20]]" is not a magic square.
--------------------------------------------------
 "[[1, 14, 4, 15], [8, 11, 5, 10], [13, 2, 16, 3], [12, 7, 9, 6]]" is a magic square.
--------------------------------------------------
 "[[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]]" is a magic square.
```

#### Source

- [Magic Square - Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I normally don't like to do complete rewrites for reviews as I don't think that they're usually helpful. Here though, the major problem that I see with your code is you're trying to do far too much "manually". You aren't making good use of built-in Python constructs that automate some of the painful elements. You also have everything in one massive block. I rewrote this from scratch to show how I'd approach the problem fresh.

There are a few discrete problems to solve here:

- Check that each sums correctly:

  - Rows
  - Columns
  - Diagonals
- Check that the square is in fact a square.
- Check that it contains the correct set of numbers.

I see each of these as distinct problems that should be handled separately. In your current code, you have everything mixed together in one massive function which makes it difficult to tell what is responsible for what job. It's simply not very easy code to read.

I ended up breaking the problem up into multiple *tiny* functions, then tying everything together in `is_magic_square`:

```
from typing import List, Iterable, Callable
from functools import partial

Grid = List[List[int]]  # Might as well create an alias for this

def has_correct_dimensions(grid: Grid) -> bool:
    """Returns whether or not the grid is a non-jagged square."""
    return all(len(row) == len(grid) for row in grid)


def is_normal_square(grid: Grid) -> bool:
    """Returns whether or not the function contains unique numbers from 1 to n**2."""
    max_n = len(grid[0]) ** 2
    # Does the set of numbers in the flattened grid contain the same numbers as a range set from 1 to n**2?
    return set(e for row in grid for e in row) == set(range(1, max_n + 1))   


def check_each(iterable: Iterable[Iterable[int]], magic_sum: int) -> bool:
    """Returns whether or not every sub-iterable collection sums to the magic sum"""
    return all(sum(elem) == magic_sum for elem in iterable)


def diagonal_of(grid: Grid, y_indexer: Callable[[int], int]) -> Iterable[int]:
    """Generates a line of elements from the grid. y = y_indexer(x)."""
    return (grid[y_indexer(x)][x] for x in range(len(grid)))


def is_magic_square(grid: Grid) -> bool:
    """Returns whether or not the supplied grid is a proper normal magic square."""
    n_rows = len(grid)
    magic_sum = n_rows * (n_rows ** 2 + 1) / 2

    check = partial(check_each, magic_sum=magic_sum)

    return is_normal_square(grid) and \
           has_correct_dimensions(grid) and \
           check(grid) and \  # Rows
           check(zip(*grid)) and \  # Columns
           check([diagonal_of(grid, lambda x: x),
                  diagonal_of(grid, lambda x: len(grid) - x - 1)])
```

Notice how I have small functions with well defined jobs. Also note how I'm making fairly extensive use of high-level Python helpers. `all` is great whenever you need to ensure that something is True across over an entire collection. And `zip` can be used to break the grid into columns.

Even with this all broken up into functions, it's still 7 lines shorter than the original. It's also ~10x faster which I certainly didn't expect since I'm doing expensive shortcut stuff like `set(e for row in grid for e in row) == set(range(1, max_n + 1))`.

My solutions is far from perfect though. Like I said above, I'm doing a few things quite wastefully. I'm using a lot of lazy operations (like with generator expressions), and repeatedly putting a whole `range` into a set over and over.

The `return` in `is_magic_square` could probably be broken up too. I think it's fine, but it might make some people gag. It could be cleaned up a bit using `all`:

```
return all([is_normal_square(grid),
            has_correct_dimensions(grid),
            check(grid),
            check(zip(*grid)),
            check([diagonal_of(grid, lambda x: x),
                   diagonal_of(grid, lambda x: len(grid) - x - 1)])])
```

At least that gets rid of the ugly line continuations.

---

The major thing in your code that I will point out though is this atrocity:

```
except:
    return False
```

I think I've mentioned this before: don't do this. If you need to catch an exception, specify the exception, and keep the `try` in the narrowest scope necessary.

Why? Because, case and point, when I tried to time your function, `timeit` was showing that your function was executing *one million times in 2 seconds*. I was blown away. Then I ran the tests though and saw that your code was returning `False` for every test. After some quick checking, I realized that I had forgotten to import numpy when I pasted your code.

Your code was returning a valid result even though the required packages for the code to run weren't even imported. Stuff like that will eventually bite you via long, painful debugging sessions. Silencing errors is, in my opinion, literally one of the worst things you can possibly do when programming.

Answer (score 4):

One should almost never use a bare `except` clause.  It should always list the exceptions to be caught.

The code would be easier to read and understand, if it were written in section that each tested one aspect of a magic square.  Like, is is a square, does it have all the numbers in sequence, do the rows add up to the magic number, do the columns, do the diagonals.   Here is a pure python version:

```
def is_magic_square(grid: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
    """Returns a boolean if an input grid is magic square"""

    grid_length = len(grid)
    grid_area = grid_length**2
    magic_sum = float(grid_length * (grid_length ** 2 + 1) / 2)

    # check the length of all rows
    if any(len(row) != grid_length for row in grid):
        return False

    # check it has all the numbers in sequence        
    if set(x for row in grid for x in row) != set(range(1, grid_area + 1)):
        return False

    # check all the rows add up to the magic_number
    if any(sum(row) != magic_sum for row in grid):
        return False

    # check all the columns add up to the magic_number
    if any(sum(row[col] for row in grid) != magic_sum for col in range(grid_length)):
        return False

    # check each diagonal adds up to the magic_number
    if (sum(grid[i][i] for i in range(grid_length)) != magic_sum
        or sum(grid[i][grid_length-i-1] for i in range(grid_length)) != magic_sum  ):
        return False

    return True
```

Your code used numpy, it has many useful functions for this task.  So here is an alternative version using numpy:

```
def is_magic_square2(grid: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
    """Returns a boolean if an input grid is magic square"""

    grid_length = len(grid)
    magic_sum = float(grid_length * (grid_length ** 2 + 1) / 2)

    # check the length of all rows
    if any(len(row) != grid_length for row in grid):
        return False

    npgrid = np.array(grid)

    # check it has all ints from 1 to grid_length**2 (inclusive)
    if len(np.setdiff1d(npgrid, np.arange(1, grid_length**2 + 1))):
        return False

    # check all the rows add up to the magic_number
    if any(np.not_equal(npgrid.sum(axis=0), magic_sum)):
        return False

    # check all the columns add up to the magic_number
    if any(np.not_equal(npgrid.sum(axis=1), magic_sum)):
        return False

    # check both diagonals add up to the magic_number
    if (npgrid.diagonal().sum() != magic_sum
        or np.fliplr(npgrid).diagonal().sum() != magic_sum):
        return False

    return True
```