# Magic Square with Five Methods (Python)

Tags: python, performance, beginner, algorithm, mathematics

#### Problem

Write a program to return a boolean if an input grid is magic square.

---

A magic square of order \$N\$ is an arrangement of \$N^2\$ distinct integers in a square such that the \$N\$ numbers in all rows and columns and both diagonals sum to the same constant, known as magic sum or magic constant, \$magic\_sum\$. A magic square contains the integers from \$1\$ to \$N^2\$.

The magic sum of a normal magic square depends only on one variable, \$N\$:

> ## \$magic\_sum = \dfrac{N(N^2+1)}{2}\$

[image: magic sum formula]

#### Code

[We've solved "if a grid is magic square" problem with five methods](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230972/magic-square-python), which I've just slightly modified those and included `timeit` benchmarking. If you would like to review the code, or add other methods or anything else or provide any change/improvement recommendations please do so, and I'd really appreciate that.

```
import numpy as np
from typing import List, Iterable, Callable
from functools import partial

Grid = List[List[int]]  # Might as well create an alias for this


def has_correct_dimensions(grid: Grid) -> bool:
    """Returns whether or not the grid is a non-jagged square."""
    return all(len(row) == len(grid) for row in grid)


def is_normal_square(grid: Grid) -> bool:
    """Returns whether or not the function contains unique numbers from 1 to n**2."""
    max_n = len(grid[0]) ** 2
    # Does the set of numbers in the flattened grid contain the same numbers as a range set from 1 to n**2?
    return set(e for row in grid for e in row) == set(range(1, max_n + 1))


def check_each(iterable: Iterable[Iterable[int]], magic_sum: int) -> bool:
    """Returns whether or not every sub-iterable collection sums to the magic sum"""
    return all(sum(elem) == magic_sum for elem in iterable)


def diagonal_of(grid: Grid, y_indexer: Callable[[int], int]) -> Iterable[int]:
    """Generates a line of elements from the grid. y = y_indexer(x)."""
    return (grid[y_indexer(x)][x] for x in range(len(grid)))


def magic_constant(grid: Grid) -> int:
    """Returns the magic sum integer value"""
    return len(grid) * (len(grid) ** 2 + 1) / 2


def is_magic_square_multifunctions(grid: Grid) -> bool:
    """Returns whether or not the supplied grid is a proper normal magic square."""

    magic_sum = magic_constant(grid)

    check = partial(check_each, magic_sum=magic_sum)

    return is_normal_square(grid) and \
        has_correct_dimensions(grid) and \
        check(grid) and \
        check(zip(*grid)) and \
        check([diagonal_of(grid, lambda x: x),
               diagonal_of(grid, lambda x: len(grid) - x - 1)])


def is_magic_square_linguini(grid: Grid) -> bool:
    length = len(grid)
    if length == 0:
        return False

    magic_sum = magic_constant(grid)

    sum_three, sum_four = int(), int()
    for index_row in range(length):
        sum_one, sum_two = int(), int()
        unique_elements = dict()
        for index_col in range(length):
            if grid[index_row][index_col] in unique_elements:
                return False
            unique_elements[grid[index_row][index_col]] = True

            sum_one += grid[index_row][index_col]
            sum_two += grid[index_col][index_row]
            if index_row == index_col:
                sum_three += grid[index_col][index_row]
            if (index_row + index_col) == length - 1:
                sum_four += grid[index_row][index_col]
        if sum_one != magic_sum or sum_two != magic_sum:
            return False

    if sum_three != magic_sum or sum_four != magic_sum:
        return False
    return True


def is_magic_square_vermicelli(grid: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
    """Returns a boolean if an input grid is magic square"""
    grid_length = len(grid)
    magic_sum = magic_constant(grid)
    diag_positive, diag_negative = [], []
    diag_count_positive, diag_count_negative = 0, grid_length - 1
    col_grid = np.zeros(shape=(grid_length, grid_length))
    unique_elements = set()
    for index_row, lists in enumerate(grid):
        diag_negative.append(lists[diag_count_negative])
        diag_count_negative -= 1

        if len(grid[index_row]) != grid_length:
            return False

        if sum(lists) != magic_sum:
            return False

        for index_col in range(grid_length):
            unique_elements.add(lists[index_col])
            col_grid[index_col][index_row] = lists[index_col]
            if index_col == grid_length and index_row == grid_length - 1 and len(unique_elements) != grid_length ** 2 - 1:
                return False

        if index_row == grid_length - 1:
            sum_col, temp_col = sum(col_grid), np.array(
                [magic_sum] * grid_length)
            if str(temp_col) != str(sum_col):
                return False

        if diag_count_positive == index_row:
            diag_positive.append(lists[index_row])
            diag_count_positive += 1

        if diag_count_positive == grid_length and sum(diag_positive) != magic_sum:
            return False

        if index_row == grid_length - 1 and sum(diag_negative) != magic_sum:
            return False

    return True


def is_magic_square_single_method(grid: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
    """Returns a boolean if an input grid is magic square"""

    grid_length = len(grid)
    grid_area = grid_length ** 2
    magic_sum = magic_constant(grid)

    # check the length of all rows
    if any(len(row) != grid_length for row in grid):
        return False

    # check it has all the numbers in sequence
    if set(x for row in grid for x in row) != set(range(1, grid_area + 1)):
        return False

    # check all the rows add up to the magic_number
    if any(sum(row) != magic_sum for row in grid):
        return False

    # check all the columns add up to the magic_number
    if any(sum(row[col] for row in grid) != magic_sum for col in range(grid_length)):
        return False

    # check each diagonal adds up to the magic_number
    if (sum(grid[i][i] for i in range(grid_length)) != magic_sum
            or sum(grid[i][grid_length - i - 1] for i in range(grid_length)) != magic_sum):
        return False

    return True


def is_magic_square_numpy(grid: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
    """Returns a boolean if an input grid is magic square"""

    grid_length = len(grid)
    magic_sum = magic_constant(grid)

    # check the length of all rows
    if any(len(row) != grid_length for row in grid):
        return False

    npgrid = np.array(grid)

    # check it has all ints from 1 to grid_length**2 (inclusive)
    if len(np.setdiff1d(npgrid, np.arange(1, grid_length ** 2 + 1))):
        return False

    # check all the rows add up to the magic_number
    if any(np.not_equal(npgrid.sum(axis=0), magic_sum)):
        return False

    # check all the columns add up to the magic_number
    if any(np.not_equal(npgrid.sum(axis=1), magic_sum)):
        return False

    # check both diagonals add up to the magic_number
    if (npgrid.diagonal().sum() != magic_sum
            or np.fliplr(npgrid).diagonal().sum() != magic_sum):
        return False

    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ---------------------------- TEST ---------------------------
    import timeit
    import cProfile

    DIVIDER_DASH_LINE = '-' * 50
    GREEN_APPLE = '\U0001F34F'
    RED_APPLE = '\U0001F34E'

    magic_squares = (
        [[4, 3, 8],
         [9, 5, 1],
         [2, 7, 6]],

        [[8, 1, 6],
         [3, 5, 7],
         [4, 9, 2]],


        [[1, 14, 4, 15],
         [8, 11, 5, 10],
         [13, 2, 16, 3],
         [12, 7, 9, 6]],


        [[9, 3, 22, 16, 15],
         [2, 21, 20, 14, 8],
         [25, 19, 13, 7, 1],
         [18, 12, 6, 5, 24],
         [11, 10, 4, 23, 17]],

        [[16, 14, 7, 30, 23],
         [24, 17, 10, 8, 31],
         [32, 25, 18, 11, 4],
         [5, 28, 26, 19, 12],
         [13, 6, 29, 22, 20]],


        [[1, 35, 4, 33, 32, 6],
         [25, 11, 9, 28, 8, 30],
         [24, 14, 18, 16, 17, 22],
         [13, 23, 19, 21, 20, 15],
         [12, 26, 27, 10, 29, 7],
         [36, 2, 34, 3, 5, 31]],


        [[35, 26, 17, 1, 62, 53, 44],
         [46, 37, 21, 12, 3, 64, 55],
         [57, 41, 32, 23, 14, 5, 66],
         [61, 52, 43, 34, 25, 16, 7],
         [2, 63, 54, 45, 36, 27, 11],
         [13, 4, 65, 56, 47, 31, 22],
         [24, 15, 6, 67, 51, 42, 33]],


        [[60, 53, 44, 37, 4, 13, 20, 29],
         [3, 14, 19, 30, 59, 54, 43, 38],
         [58, 55, 42, 39, 2, 15, 18, 31],
         [1, 16, 17, 32, 57, 56, 41, 40],
         [61, 52, 45, 36, 5, 12, 21, 28],
         [6, 11, 22, 27, 62, 51, 46, 35],
         [63, 50, 47, 34, 7, 10, 23, 26],
         [8, 9, 24, 25, 64, 49, 48, 33]],


        [[22, 47, 16, 41, 10, 35, 4],
         [5, 23, 48, 17, 42, 11, 29],
            [30, 6, 24, 49, 18, 36, 12],
            [13, 31, 7, 25, 43, 19, 37],
            [38, 14, 32, 1, 26, 44, 20],
            [21, 39, 8, 33, 2, 27, 45],
            [46, 15, 40, 9, 34, 3, 28]],

        [[8, 58, 59, 5, 4, 62, 63, 1],
         [49, 15, 14, 52, 53, 11, 10, 56],
            [41, 23, 22, 44, 45, 19, 18, 48],
            [32, 34, 35, 29, 28, 38, 39, 25],
            [40, 26, 27, 37, 36, 30, 31, 33],
            [17, 47, 46, 20, 21, 43, 42, 24],
            [9, 55, 54, 12, 13, 51, 50, 16],
            [64, 2, 3, 61, 60, 6, 7, 57]],

        [[37, 78, 29, 70, 21, 62, 13, 54, 5],
         [6, 38, 79, 30, 71, 22, 63, 14, 46],
            [47, 7, 39, 80, 31, 72, 23, 55, 15],
            [16, 48, 8, 40, 81, 32, 64, 24, 56],
            [57, 17, 49, 9, 41, 73, 33, 65, 25],
            [26, 58, 18, 50, 1, 42, 74, 34, 66],
            [67, 27, 59, 10, 51, 2, 43, 75, 35],
            [36, 68, 19, 60, 11, 52, 3, 44, 76],
            [77, 28, 69, 20, 61, 12, 53, 4, 45]],

    )

    test_methods = (
        ("Multifunctions", is_magic_square_multifunctions),
        ("Linguine", is_magic_square_linguini),
        ("Vermicelli", is_magic_square_vermicelli),
        ("Single Method", is_magic_square_single_method),
        ("Numpy", is_magic_square_numpy),
    )

    # --------------------------------- PROFILING AND BANCHMARK SETTINGS --------------------------------------
    NUMBER_OF_RUNS = 64
    CPROFILING_ON = False
    BENCHMARK_ON = True

    for description, method in test_methods:
        print((GREEN_APPLE + RED_APPLE) * 5)

        for magic_square in magic_squares:
            if CPROFILING_ON is True:
                print(f'{description} cProfiling: ', cProfile.run("method(magic_square)"))
            if BENCHMARK_ON is True:
                print(f'{description} Benchmark: ', timeit.Timer(
                    f'for i in range({NUMBER_OF_RUNS}): {method(magic_square)}', 'gc.enable()').timeit())

            if method(magic_square) is True:
                print(f'{GREEN_APPLE} {description}: "{magic_square}" is a magic square.')
            else:
                print(f'{RED_APPLE} {description}: "{magic_square}" is not a magic square.')
```

#### Test

These variables can be assigned differently for testing:

```
NUMBER_OF_RUNS = 64
CPROFILING_ON = False
BENCHMARK_ON = True
```

#### A Sample Output

```
Multifunctions Benchmark:  5.588784874
 Multifunctions: "[[4, 3, 8], [9, 5, 1], [2, 7, 6]]" is a magic square.
Multifunctions Benchmark:  5.549960512000001
 Multifunctions: "[[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]]" is a magic square.
Multifunctions Benchmark:  5.783070463
 Multifunctions: "[[1, 14, 4, 15], [8, 11, 5, 10], [13, 2, 16, 3], [12, 7, 9, 6]]" is a magic square.
Multifunctions Benchmark:  6.041834480999999
 Multifunctions: "[[9, 3, 22, 16, 15], [2, 21, 20, 14, 8], [25, 19, 13, 7, 1], [18, 12, 6, 5, 24], [11, 10, 4, 23, 17]]" is a magic square.
Multifunctions Benchmark:  6.304372493999999
 Multifunctions: "[[16, 14, 7, 30, 23], [24, 17, 10, 8, 31], [32, 25, 18, 11, 4], [5, 28, 26, 19, 12], [13, 6, 29, 22, 20]]" is not a magic square.
Multifunctions Benchmark:  6.737646978000001
 Multifunctions: "[[1, 35, 4, 33, 32, 6], [25, 11, 9, 28, 8, 30], [24, 14, 18, 16, 17, 22], [13, 23, 19, 21, 20, 15], [12, 26, 27, 10, 29, 7], [36, 2, 34, 3, 5, 31]]" is a magic square.
Multifunctions Benchmark:  6.330970278999999
 Multifunctions: "[[35, 26, 17, 1, 62, 53, 44], [46, 37, 21, 12, 3, 64, 55], [57, 41, 32, 23, 14, 5, 66], [61, 52, 43, 34, 25, 16, 7], [2, 63, 54, 45, 36, 27, 11], [13, 4, 65, 56, 47, 31, 22], [24, 15, 6, 67, 51, 42, 33]]" is not a magic square.
Multifunctions Benchmark:  6.320764873000002
 Multifunctions: "[[60, 53, 44, 37, 4, 13, 20, 29], [3, 14, 19, 30, 59, 54, 43, 38], [58, 55, 42, 39, 2, 15, 18, 31], [1, 16, 17, 32, 57, 56, 41, 40], [61, 52, 45, 36, 5, 12, 21, 28], [6, 11, 22, 27, 62, 51, 46, 35], [63, 50, 47, 34, 7, 10, 23, 26], [8, 9, 24, 25, 64, 49, 48, 33]]" is a magic square.
Multifunctions Benchmark:  6.070653400000005
 Multifunctions: "[[22, 47, 16, 41, 10, 35, 4], [5, 23, 48, 17, 42, 11, 29], [30, 6, 24, 49, 18, 36, 12], [13, 31, 7, 25, 43, 19, 37], [38, 14, 32, 1, 26, 44, 20], [21, 39, 8, 33, 2, 27, 45], [46, 15, 40, 9, 34, 3, 28]]" is a magic square.
Multifunctions Benchmark:  5.944438742000003
 Multifunctions: "[[8, 58, 59, 5, 4, 62, 63, 1], [49, 15, 14, 52, 53, 11, 10, 56], [41, 23, 22, 44, 45, 19, 18, 48], [32, 34, 35, 29, 28, 38, 39, 25], [40, 26, 27, 37, 36, 30, 31, 33], [17, 47, 46, 20, 21, 43, 42, 24], [9, 55, 54, 12, 13, 51, 50, 16], [64, 2, 3, 61, 60, 6, 7, 57]]" is a magic square.
Multifunctions Benchmark:  5.747417926999994
 Multifunctions: "[[37, 78, 29, 70, 21, 62, 13, 54, 5], [6, 38, 79, 30, 71, 22, 63, 14, 46], [47, 7, 39, 80, 31, 72, 23, 55, 15], [16, 48, 8, 40, 81, 32, 64, 24, 56], [57, 17, 49, 9, 41, 73, 33, 65, 25], [26, 58, 18, 50, 1, 42, 74, 34, 66], [67, 27, 59, 10, 51, 2, 43, 75, 35], [36, 68, 19, 60, 11, 52, 3, 44, 76], [77, 28, 69, 20, 61, 12, 53, 4, 45]]" is a magic square.

Linguine Benchmark:  5.696244382999993
 Linguine: "[[4, 3, 8], [9, 5, 1], [2, 7, 6]]" is a magic square.
Linguine Benchmark:  5.674139272000005
 Linguine: "[[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]]" is a magic square.
Linguine Benchmark:  5.92109452599999
 Linguine: "[[1, 14, 4, 15], [8, 11, 5, 10], [13, 2, 16, 3], [12, 7, 9, 6]]" is a magic square.
Linguine Benchmark:  5.958363641999995
 Linguine: "[[9, 3, 22, 16, 15], [2, 21, 20, 14, 8], [25, 19, 13, 7, 1], [18, 12, 6, 5, 24], [11, 10, 4, 23, 17]]" is a magic square.
Linguine Benchmark:  5.686515516
 Linguine: "[[16, 14, 7, 30, 23], [24, 17, 10, 8, 31], [32, 25, 18, 11, 4], [5, 28, 26, 19, 12], [13, 6, 29, 22, 20]]" is not a magic square.
Linguine Benchmark:  5.728992446999996
 Linguine: "[[1, 35, 4, 33, 32, 6], [25, 11, 9, 28, 8, 30], [24, 14, 18, 16, 17, 22], [13, 23, 19, 21, 20, 15], [12, 26, 27, 10, 29, 7], [36, 2, 34, 3, 5, 31]]" is a magic square.
Linguine Benchmark:  5.650582772000007
 Linguine: "[[35, 26, 17, 1, 62, 53, 44], [46, 37, 21, 12, 3, 64, 55], [57, 41, 32, 23, 14, 5, 66], [61, 52, 43, 34, 25, 16, 7], [2, 63, 54, 45, 36, 27, 11], [13, 4, 65, 56, 47, 31, 22], [24, 15, 6, 67, 51, 42, 33]]" is not a magic square.
Linguine Benchmark:  5.616721932000004
 Linguine: "[[60, 53, 44, 37, 4, 13, 20, 29], [3, 14, 19, 30, 59, 54, 43, 38], [58, 55, 42, 39, 2, 15, 18, 31], [1, 16, 17, 32, 57, 56, 41, 40], [61, 52, 45, 36, 5, 12, 21, 28], [6, 11, 22, 27, 62, 51, 46, 35], [63, 50, 47, 34, 7, 10, 23, 26], [8, 9, 24, 25, 64, 49, 48, 33]]" is a magic square.
Linguine Benchmark:  5.492888303000001
 Linguine: "[[22, 47, 16, 41, 10, 35, 4], [5, 23, 48, 17, 42, 11, 29], [30, 6, 24, 49, 18, 36, 12], [13, 31, 7, 25, 43, 19, 37], [38, 14, 32, 1, 26, 44, 20], [21, 39, 8, 33, 2, 27, 45], [46, 15, 40, 9, 34, 3, 28]]" is a magic square.
Linguine Benchmark:  5.574545161999993
 Linguine: "[[8, 58, 59, 5, 4, 62, 63, 1], [49, 15, 14, 52, 53, 11, 10, 56], [41, 23, 22, 44, 45, 19, 18, 48], [32, 34, 35, 29, 28, 38, 39, 25], [40, 26, 27, 37, 36, 30, 31, 33], [17, 47, 46, 20, 21, 43, 42, 24], [9, 55, 54, 12, 13, 51, 50, 16], [64, 2, 3, 61, 60, 6, 7, 57]]" is a magic square.
Linguine Benchmark:  5.479747597999989
 Linguine: "[[37, 78, 29, 70, 21, 62, 13, 54, 5], [6, 38, 79, 30, 71, 22, 63, 14, 46], [47, 7, 39, 80, 31, 72, 23, 55, 15], [16, 48, 8, 40, 81, 32, 64, 24, 56], [57, 17, 49, 9, 41, 73, 33, 65, 25], [26, 58, 18, 50, 1, 42, 74, 34, 66], [67, 27, 59, 10, 51, 2, 43, 75, 35], [36, 68, 19, 60, 11, 52, 3, 44, 76], [77, 28, 69, 20, 61, 12, 53, 4, 45]]" is a magic square.

Vermicelli Benchmark:  5.610320167999987
 Vermicelli: "[[4, 3, 8], [9, 5, 1], [2, 7, 6]]" is a magic square.
Vermicelli Benchmark:  5.473386472000016
 Vermicelli: "[[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]]" is a magic square.
Vermicelli Benchmark:  5.50186076
 Vermicelli: "[[1, 14, 4, 15], [8, 11, 5, 10], [13, 2, 16, 3], [12, 7, 9, 6]]" is a magic square.
Vermicelli Benchmark:  5.465219862999987
 Vermicelli: "[[9, 3, 22, 16, 15], [2, 21, 20, 14, 8], [25, 19, 13, 7, 1], [18, 12, 6, 5, 24], [11, 10, 4, 23, 17]]" is a magic square.
Vermicelli Benchmark:  5.538681058999998
 Vermicelli: "[[16, 14, 7, 30, 23], [24, 17, 10, 8, 31], [32, 25, 18, 11, 4], [5, 28, 26, 19, 12], [13, 6, 29, 22, 20]]" is not a magic square.
Vermicelli Benchmark:  5.466972800000008
 Vermicelli: "[[1, 35, 4, 33, 32, 6], [25, 11, 9, 28, 8, 30], [24, 14, 18, 16, 17, 22], [13, 23, 19, 21, 20, 15], [12, 26, 27, 10, 29, 7], [36, 2, 34, 3, 5, 31]]" is a magic square.
Vermicelli Benchmark:  5.542082810000011
 Vermicelli: "[[35, 26, 17, 1, 62, 53, 44], [46, 37, 21, 12, 3, 64, 55], [57, 41, 32, 23, 14, 5, 66], [61, 52, 43, 34, 25, 16, 7], [2, 63, 54, 45, 36, 27, 11], [13, 4, 65, 56, 47, 31, 22], [24, 15, 6, 67, 51, 42, 33]]" is not a magic square.
Vermicelli Benchmark:  5.477112298999998
 Vermicelli: "[[60, 53, 44, 37, 4, 13, 20, 29], [3, 14, 19, 30, 59, 54, 43, 38], [58, 55, 42, 39, 2, 15, 18, 31], [1, 16, 17, 32, 57, 56, 41, 40], [61, 52, 45, 36, 5, 12, 21, 28], [6, 11, 22, 27, 62, 51, 46, 35], [63, 50, 47, 34, 7, 10, 23, 26], [8, 9, 24, 25, 64, 49, 48, 33]]" is a magic square.
Vermicelli Benchmark:  5.534445683000001
 Vermicelli: "[[22, 47, 16, 41, 10, 35, 4], [5, 23, 48, 17, 42, 11, 29], [30, 6, 24, 49, 18, 36, 12], [13, 31, 7, 25, 43, 19, 37], [38, 14, 32, 1, 26, 44, 20], [21, 39, 8, 33, 2, 27, 45], [46, 15, 40, 9, 34, 3, 28]]" is a magic square.
Vermicelli Benchmark:  5.473650165999999
 Vermicelli: "[[8, 58, 59, 5, 4, 62, 63, 1], [49, 15, 14, 52, 53, 11, 10, 56], [41, 23, 22, 44, 45, 19, 18, 48], [32, 34, 35, 29, 28, 38, 39, 25], [40, 26, 27, 37, 36, 30, 31, 33], [17, 47, 46, 20, 21, 43, 42, 24], [9, 55, 54, 12, 13, 51, 50, 16], [64, 2, 3, 61, 60, 6, 7, 57]]" is a magic square.
Vermicelli Benchmark:  5.516359977000008
 Vermicelli: "[[37, 78, 29, 70, 21, 62, 13, 54, 5], [6, 38, 79, 30, 71, 22, 63, 14, 46], [47, 7, 39, 80, 31, 72, 23, 55, 15], [16, 48, 8, 40, 81, 32, 64, 24, 56], [57, 17, 49, 9, 41, 73, 33, 65, 25], [26, 58, 18, 50, 1, 42, 74, 34, 66], [67, 27, 59, 10, 51, 2, 43, 75, 35], [36, 68, 19, 60, 11, 52, 3, 44, 76], [77, 28, 69, 20, 61, 12, 53, 4, 45]]" is a magic square.

Single Method Benchmark:  5.792159653999988
 Single Method: "[[4, 3, 8], [9, 5, 1], [2, 7, 6]]" is a magic square.
Single Method Benchmark:  5.452938262999993
 Single Method: "[[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]]" is a magic square.
Single Method Benchmark:  5.8117709149999826
 Single Method: "[[1, 14, 4, 15], [8, 11, 5, 10], [13, 2, 16, 3], [12, 7, 9, 6]]" is a magic square.
Single Method Benchmark:  5.46323830099999
 Single Method: "[[9, 3, 22, 16, 15], [2, 21, 20, 14, 8], [25, 19, 13, 7, 1], [18, 12, 6, 5, 24], [11, 10, 4, 23, 17]]" is a magic square.
Single Method Benchmark:  5.8472462789999895
 Single Method: "[[16, 14, 7, 30, 23], [24, 17, 10, 8, 31], [32, 25, 18, 11, 4], [5, 28, 26, 19, 12], [13, 6, 29, 22, 20]]" is not a magic square.
Single Method Benchmark:  5.433652160999998
 Single Method: "[[1, 35, 4, 33, 32, 6], [25, 11, 9, 28, 8, 30], [24, 14, 18, 16, 17, 22], [13, 23, 19, 21, 20, 15], [12, 26, 27, 10, 29, 7], [36, 2, 34, 3, 5, 31]]" is a magic square.
Single Method Benchmark:  5.805129637999983
 Single Method: "[[35, 26, 17, 1, 62, 53, 44], [46, 37, 21, 12, 3, 64, 55], [57, 41, 32, 23, 14, 5, 66], [61, 52, 43, 34, 25, 16, 7], [2, 63, 54, 45, 36, 27, 11], [13, 4, 65, 56, 47, 31, 22], [24, 15, 6, 67, 51, 42, 33]]" is not a magic square.
Single Method Benchmark:  5.48093770700001
 Single Method: "[[60, 53, 44, 37, 4, 13, 20, 29], [3, 14, 19, 30, 59, 54, 43, 38], [58, 55, 42, 39, 2, 15, 18, 31], [1, 16, 17, 32, 57, 56, 41, 40], [61, 52, 45, 36, 5, 12, 21, 28], [6, 11, 22, 27, 62, 51, 46, 35], [63, 50, 47, 34, 7, 10, 23, 26], [8, 9, 24, 25, 64, 49, 48, 33]]" is a magic square.
Single Method Benchmark:  5.818483440999984
 Single Method: "[[22, 47, 16, 41, 10, 35, 4], [5, 23, 48, 17, 42, 11, 29], [30, 6, 24, 49, 18, 36, 12], [13, 31, 7, 25, 43, 19, 37], [38, 14, 32, 1, 26, 44, 20], [21, 39, 8, 33, 2, 27, 45], [46, 15, 40, 9, 34, 3, 28]]" is a magic square.
Single Method Benchmark:  5.494786433999991
 Single Method: "[[8, 58, 59, 5, 4, 62, 63, 1], [49, 15, 14, 52, 53, 11, 10, 56], [41, 23, 22, 44, 45, 19, 18, 48], [32, 34, 35, 29, 28, 38, 39, 25], [40, 26, 27, 37, 36, 30, 31, 33], [17, 47, 46, 20, 21, 43, 42, 24], [9, 55, 54, 12, 13, 51, 50, 16], [64, 2, 3, 61, 60, 6, 7, 57]]" is a magic square.
Single Method Benchmark:  5.769875240999994
 Single Method: "[[37, 78, 29, 70, 21, 62, 13, 54, 5], [6, 38, 79, 30, 71, 22, 63, 14, 46], [47, 7, 39, 80, 31, 72, 23, 55, 15], [16, 48, 8, 40, 81, 32, 64, 24, 56], [57, 17, 49, 9, 41, 73, 33, 65, 25], [26, 58, 18, 50, 1, 42, 74, 34, 66], [67, 27, 59, 10, 51, 2, 43, 75, 35], [36, 68, 19, 60, 11, 52, 3, 44, 76], [77, 28, 69, 20, 61, 12, 53, 4, 45]]" is a magic square.

Numpy Benchmark:  5.541609400999988
 Numpy: "[[4, 3, 8], [9, 5, 1], [2, 7, 6]]" is a magic square.
Numpy Benchmark:  5.829946971000027
 Numpy: "[[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]]" is a magic square.
Numpy Benchmark:  5.444178211999997
 Numpy: "[[1, 14, 4, 15], [8, 11, 5, 10], [13, 2, 16, 3], [12, 7, 9, 6]]" is a magic square.
Numpy Benchmark:  5.820747697000002
 Numpy: "[[9, 3, 22, 16, 15], [2, 21, 20, 14, 8], [25, 19, 13, 7, 1], [18, 12, 6, 5, 24], [11, 10, 4, 23, 17]]" is a magic square.
Numpy Benchmark:  5.5407621650000465
 Numpy: "[[16, 14, 7, 30, 23], [24, 17, 10, 8, 31], [32, 25, 18, 11, 4], [5, 28, 26, 19, 12], [13, 6, 29, 22, 20]]" is not a magic square.
Numpy Benchmark:  5.764756991000013
 Numpy: "[[1, 35, 4, 33, 32, 6], [25, 11, 9, 28, 8, 30], [24, 14, 18, 16, 17, 22], [13, 23, 19, 21, 20, 15], [12, 26, 27, 10, 29, 7], [36, 2, 34, 3, 5, 31]]" is a magic square.
Numpy Benchmark:  5.588026968999998
 Numpy: "[[35, 26, 17, 1, 62, 53, 44], [46, 37, 21, 12, 3, 64, 55], [57, 41, 32, 23, 14, 5, 66], [61, 52, 43, 34, 25, 16, 7], [2, 63, 54, 45, 36, 27, 11], [13, 4, 65, 56, 47, 31, 22], [24, 15, 6, 67, 51, 42, 33]]" is not a magic square.
Numpy Benchmark:  5.712816462999967
 Numpy: "[[60, 53, 44, 37, 4, 13, 20, 29], [3, 14, 19, 30, 59, 54, 43, 38], [58, 55, 42, 39, 2, 15, 18, 31], [1, 16, 17, 32, 57, 56, 41, 40], [61, 52, 45, 36, 5, 12, 21, 28], [6, 11, 22, 27, 62, 51, 46, 35], [63, 50, 47, 34, 7, 10, 23, 26], [8, 9, 24, 25, 64, 49, 48, 33]]" is a magic square.
Numpy Benchmark:  5.540658426999983
 Numpy: "[[22, 47, 16, 41, 10, 35, 4], [5, 23, 48, 17, 42, 11, 29], [30, 6, 24, 49, 18, 36, 12], [13, 31, 7, 25, 43, 19, 37], [38, 14, 32, 1, 26, 44, 20], [21, 39, 8, 33, 2, 27, 45], [46, 15, 40, 9, 34, 3, 28]]" is a magic square.
Numpy Benchmark:  5.761296496999989
 Numpy: "[[8, 58, 59, 5, 4, 62, 63, 1], [49, 15, 14, 52, 53, 11, 10, 56], [41, 23, 22, 44, 45, 19, 18, 48], [32, 34, 35, 29, 28, 38, 39, 25], [40, 26, 27, 37, 36, 30, 31, 33], [17, 47, 46, 20, 21, 43, 42, 24], [9, 55, 54, 12, 13, 51, 50, 16], [64, 2, 3, 61, 60, 6, 7, 57]]" is a magic square.
Numpy Benchmark:  5.583522877999997
 Numpy: "[[37, 78, 29, 70, 21, 62, 13, 54, 5], [6, 38, 79, 30, 71, 22, 63, 14, 46], [47, 7, 39, 80, 31, 72, 23, 55, 15], [16, 48, 8, 40, 81, 32, 64, 24, 56], [57, 17, 49, 9, 41, 73, 33, 65, 25], [26, 58, 18, 50, 1, 42, 74, 34, 66], [67, 27, 59, 10, 51, 2, 43, 75, 35], [36, 68, 19, 60, 11, 52, 3, 44, 76], [77, 28, 69, 20, 61, 12, 53, 4, 45]]" is a magic square.
```

#### Source

- [Magic Square (Python)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230972/magic-square-python)
- [Magic Squares In Grid - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/magic-squares-in-grid/)
- [Magic Square - Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/magic-square/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall this is quite reasonable. Good job!

### Boolean conditions

No need to write

```
        if CPROFILING_ON is True:
```

Just write

```
        if CPROFILING_ON:
```

### Int constructor

This:

```
    sum_one, sum_two = int(), int()
```

is just a goofier way of writing

```
    sum_one, sum_two = 0, 0
```

The latter is clearer.

### Set instead of dict

`unique_elements` should be a `set`, not a `dict`. You never use the value, just the key.

### Line continuations

```
return is_normal_square(grid) and \
    has_correct_dimensions(grid) and \
    check(grid) and \
    check(zip(*grid)) and \
    check([diagonal_of(grid, lambda x: x),
           diagonal_of(grid, lambda x: len(grid) - x - 1)])
```

has a lot of continuations; preferred is usually

```
return (
    is_normal_square(grid) and
    has_correct_dimensions(grid) and
    check(grid) and
    check(zip(*grid)) and
    check([diagonal_of(grid, lambda x: x),
           diagonal_of(grid, lambda x: len(grid) - x - 1)])
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with conditional returns. A benefit with this approach is that it saves time by not doing a full check as soon as a non-magic property is discovered. This function takes `square` as a list of lists (rows).

```
from typing import List

def is_really_magic(square: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
    dim = len(square)
    magic_const = dim * (dim**2 +1) // 2
    dia_sum = 0
    dia_sum2 = 0
    for y in range(dim):
        if sum(square[y]) != magic_const:
            return False
        col_sum = 0
        for row in square:
            col_sum += row[y]
        if col_sum != magic_const:
            return False        
        dia_sum += square[y][y]
        dia_sum2 += square[y][dim-1-y]
    if dia_sum != magic_const or dia_sum2 != magic_const:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Thank you for supplying an answer. I cleaned up the formatting. Was `:p square: ` supposed to be formatted a special way? if so, feel free to correct my change on that if formatting `square` as inline code is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the welcoming! I just use :p parameter: as a way to distinguish when I speak of parameters or variable names.